# Add image in CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, google-mlkit

I can't seem to figure out how to add image to CAShapeLayer if I add the image to CAShapeLayer contents the image become hugeee and covers the whole screen

```
static func addShapeForEyeBrows(withPoints points: [NSValue]?, to view: UIView, image: UIImage) {
    guard let points = points else { return }
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    for (index, value) in points.enumerated() {
        let point = value.cgPointValue
        if index == 0 {
            path.move(to: point)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }
        if index == points.count - 1 {
            path.close()
        }
    }
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemPink.cgColor
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    let shapeView = UIView(frame: rect)
    shapeView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.addSubview(shapeView)
}
```

So in this code am creating a custom shape with Bezier Path and using CAShapeLayer I need to add image, This function is actually creating a shape on eyebrow of the face and now just need to add image to that, I have already tried what is suggested in the other answers like adding gravity top and stuff but it completely changes the position of the image on the face so it doesn't work

Comment: It's much simple to create a separate `CALayer` which has an image, and add it as a sublayer for your `CAShapeLayer`. And you also could add the image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I’d just put my image in an image view and add this shape layer as a sublayer to that image view (not as a sublayer of a subview, either). If the image is the wrong size, change the image view’s frame and/or content mode.